# CSS property "word-break: break-all" isn't working expectedly with specific characters in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, word-break

I'm using "word-break: break-all" to insert breaks between any characters.
However, in Chrome, It's not working expectedly with specific characters (e.g colon, semicolon, comma) like below.
(My codepen is here: https://codepen.io/yukito/pen/wobZJq)

source code:

```
<style>
  .test {
    width: 300px;
    word-break: break-all;

    /* cosmetic */
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
</style>

<div class="test">
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
</div>

<div class="test">
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
</div>
```

In FireFox and Safari, it's working expectedly.

My questions:
. Is it a bug ? or a spec?
. How do I break line between continuous semicolons in Chrome ?

Thank you.

## Update:

"break-word" breaks line considering word boundaries like this pen: https://codepen.io/yukito/pen/xRNopJ 
I really want to insert breaks between any characters without considering word boundaries.

Comment: The codepen link's code working fine on both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @aavrug It doesn't work for me in Opera, and the solution I posted below seems to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `break-word` property instead of `break-all`.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```html
<style>
  .test {
    width: 300px;
    word-break: break-word;
  
    /* cosmetic */
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
</style>

<div class="test">
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
</div>

<div class="test">
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For webkit browsers, you need to add:

```
 .test {
      word-break: break-word;
    }
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/Ypbbaa)

Comment: Thx. But, "break-word" breaks line considering word boundaries like this pen: https://codepen.io/yukito/pen/wobZJq . I really want to insert breaks between any characters without considering word boundaries.

Comment: I think the reason that the word 'test' is appearing on its own line there might be that you've added a new line after it. See the second box here: https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/LboKGr   -- or am I misunderstanding you?